# Adding more then one File Transfer DL-UL communication in SimuLTE handover example

Tags: omnet++, simulate

I'm trying to add more then one download upload link to be simulated in SimuLTE handover example, specifically in File Transfer DL-UL scenario and I changed the .ini file from this:

```
#
# Communication (TCP) from ue11 to ue21 (static)
#
[Config FileTransfer-DL_UL]
extends=Handover-General

*.ue11.numTcpApps = 1
*.ue21.numTcpApps = 1

#============= Application Setup =============
# Transmitter
*.ue11.tcpApp[*].typename = "TCPSessionApp"
*.ue11.tcpApp[*].localPort = 1000
*.ue11.tcpApp[*].sendBytes = 1GiB
*.ue11.tcpApp[0].tOpen = uniform(0.010s,0.1s) 
*.ue11.tcpApp[0].tSend = uniform(0.15s,0.5s) 
*.ue11.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "ue21" 
*.ue11.tcpApp[0].localAddress = "ue11" 

# Receiver
*.ue21.tcpApp[*].typename = "TCPSinkApp"
#------------------------------------#
```

to this:

```
#
[Config FileTransfer-DL_UL]
extends=Handover-General

*.ue11.numTcpApps = 1
*.ue21.numTcpApps = 1

*.ue31.numTcpApps = 1
*.ue32.numTcpApps = 1

*.ue41.numTcpApps = 1
*.ue42.numTcpApps = 1

*.ue51.numTcpApps = 1
*.ue52.numTcpApps = 1

*.ue61.numTcpApps = 1
*.ue62.numTcpApps = 1

*.ue71.numTcpApps = 1
*.ue72.numTcpApps = 1

*.ue81.numTcpApps = 1
*.ue82.numTcpApps = 1

*.ue91.numTcpApps = 1
*.ue92.numTcpApps = 1

#============= Application Setup =============
# Transmitter
*.ue**.tcpApp[*].active = true
*.ue11.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSessionApp"
*.ue11.tcpApp[0].localPort = 1000
*.ue11.tcpApp[0].connectPort = 1000
*.ue11.tcpApp[0].sendBytes = 10MiB
*.ue11.tcpApp[0].tOpen = uniform(0.010s,0.1s) 
*.ue11.tcpApp[0].tSend = uniform(0.15s,0.5s) 
*.ue11.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "ue21" 
*.ue11.tcpApp[0].localAddress = "ue11" 

*.ue31.tcpApp[*].typename = "TCPSessionApp"
*.ue31.tcpApp[0].localPort = 1000
*.ue31.tcpApp[0].connectPort = 1000
*.ue31.tcpApp[0].sendBytes = 10MiB
*.ue31.tcpApp[0].tOpen = uniform(0.010s,0.1s) 
*.ue31.tcpApp[0].tSend = uniform(0.15s,0.5s) 
*.ue31.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "ue32" 
*.ue31.tcpApp[0].localAddress = "ue31" 

*.ue41.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSessionApp"
*.ue41.tcpApp[0].localPort = 1000
*.ue41.tcpApp[*].sendBytes = 10MiB
*.ue41.tcpApp[0].tOpen = uniform(2.010s,2.1s) 
*.ue41.tcpApp[0].tSend = uniform(2.15s,2.5s) 
*.ue41.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "ue42" 
*.ue41.tcpApp[0].localAddress = "ue41" 

*.ue51.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSessionApp"
*.ue51.tcpApp[0].localPort = 1000
*.ue51.tcpApp[0].sendBytes = 10MiB
*.ue51.tcpApp[0].tOpen = uniform(0.010s,0.1s) 
*.ue51.tcpApp[0].tSend = uniform(0.15s,0.5s) 
*.ue51.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "ue52" 
*.ue51.tcpApp[0].localAddress = "ue51" 

*.ue61.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSessionApp"
*.ue61.tcpApp[0].localPort = 1000
*.ue61.tcpApp[0].sendBytes = 10MiB
*.ue61.tcpApp[0].tOpen = uniform(0.010s,0.1s) 
*.ue61.tcpApp[0].tSend = uniform(0.15s,0.5s) 
*.ue61.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "ue62" 
*.ue61.tcpApp[0].localAddress = "ue61" 

*.ue71.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSessionApp"
*.ue71.tcpApp[0].localPort = 1000
*.ue71.tcpApp[0].sendBytes = 10MiB
*.ue71.tcpApp[0].tOpen = uniform(0.010s,0.1s) 
*.ue71.tcpApp[0].tSend = uniform(0.15s,0.5s) 
*.ue71.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "ue72" 
*.ue71.tcpApp[0].localAddress = "ue71" 

*.ue81.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSessionApp"
*.ue81.tcpApp[0].localPort = 1000
*.ue81.tcpApp[0].sendBytes = 10MiB
*.ue81.tcpApp[0].tOpen = uniform(0.010s,0.1s) 
*.ue81.tcpApp[0].tSend = uniform(0.15s,0.5s) 
*.ue81.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "ue82" 
*.ue81.tcpApp[0].localAddress = "ue81" 

*.ue91.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSessionApp"
*.ue91.tcpApp[0].localPort = 1000
*.ue91.tcpApp[0].sendBytes = 10MiB
*.ue91.tcpApp[0].tOpen = uniform(0.010s,0.1s) 
*.ue91.tcpApp[0].tSend = uniform(0.15s,0.5s) 
*.ue91.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "ue92" 
*.ue91.tcpApp[0].localAddress = "ue91" 


# Receiver
*.ue21.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSinkApp"

*.ue32.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSinkApp"


*.ue42.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSinkApp"
*.ue52.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSinkApp"
*.ue62.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSinkApp"
*.ue72.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSinkApp"
*.ue82.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSinkApp"
*.ue92.tcpApp[0].typename = "TCPSinkApp"
**.tcpApp[*].tClose = -1s
```

Simulation time is set to 20 sec. The trouble is, when the simulation finishes and I open the scalars, I see only ue11 and ue61 to be sending any data at all and ue21 is the only one to have received any packages. Could anyone help me and tell me what am I doing wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, talk about stupid, using cmdenv I forgot that I placed the eNodes too far away from UEs and that is the reason i had this problem :')